# memset slow on 32-bit embedded platform

Tags: c++, embedded, memset

I am developing on an embedded device (STM32, ARM-Cortex M4) and expected `memset` and similar functions to be optimized for speed.  However, I noticed much slower behavior than expected.  I'm using GNU ARM embedded compiler/linker (`arm-none-eabi-gcc`, etc) with the `-O3` optimization flag.

I looked into the disassembly and the `memset` function is writing one byte at a time and rechecking bounds at each iteration.

```
0x802e2c4 <memset>: add r2, r0
0x802e2c6 <memset+2>:   mov r3, r0
0x802e2c8 <memset+4>:   cmp r3, r2
0x802e2ca <memset+6>:   bne.n   0x802e2ce <memset+10>
0x802e2cc <memset+8>:   bx  lr
0x802e2ce <memset+10>:  strb.w  r1, [r3], #1
0x802e2d2 <memset+14>:  b.n 0x802e2c8
```

Naturally, this code could be sped up by using 32-bit writes and/or loop unrolling at the expense of code size.  It is possible the implementers chose not to optimize this for speed in order to keep code size down.

The `memset` header and library are being included from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools Arm Embedded\7 2018-q2-update\arm-none-eabi\include\string.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools Arm Embedded\7 2018-q2-update\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\7.3.1\cmath
```

This question is similar to existing questions but is different in that it targets an embedded platform.

**Is there an optimized memset readily available within the GNU ARM embedded package?  If so how can I access it?**

Comment: If you are developing in C++ (as tag suggests) you should be better off using `std::fill`. This has a good chance of being optimized by the compiler.

Comment: The "newlib" C library's [Source Code](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=newlib/libc/string/memset.c) is already optimized for speed and does 32bit writes. This optimization is only triggered if the memory address is properly aligned, so make sure that is the case. The `libc.a` variants from the newlib-based [GCC-ARM-Embedded](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) distribution all use said optimization. Which distribution are you using, what is your source code, how do you compile/link?

Comment: @SergeyA The performance of std::fill is the same as memset.  Why would one expect it to be better optimized than memset?

Comment: @devtk because memset (unless intrinsic) is a function provided by library and is whatever it is, and it could be generic. When you are using `std::fill`, compiler has a luxury of optimizing on the site. However, I must admit, I have seen no optimization on godbolt when tried.

Comment: @Erlkoenig I'm using [GNU Tools Arm Embedded](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm), the exact version is in the path in the question.  The linker command specifies "-specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs" among others.  It says it uses newlib, but the memset function clearly doesn't match the one you linked.

Comment: Maybe test without `-specs=nano.specs`, which might optimize for size.

Comment: @devtk : Your _comment_ regarding linker options should be included in the _question_.  _Compiler_ options such as -O3 will have no effect on the library code.  It is clear to see from the [_source_](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/string/memset.c) that there are two distinct implementations - a generic small but less efficient version, and another that deals with start/end alignment and copies the bulk using unrolled 32 bit writes. (if the size warrants it).

Comment: The CMSIS DSP package has what they call "vector fill" functions which are basically optimized versions of memset:
[CMSIS DSP Vector Fill](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__Fill.html#ga69cc781cf337bd0a31bb85c772a35f7f)

Comment: I confirm that the newlib-nano standard lib C from arm-none-eabi_gcc is doing byte per byte copy or write for memcpy and memset.

Comment: @Erlkoenig I think you're wrong : both newlib and newlib-nano memset are using "strb" instruction (8bits copy). I just gave it a try to be sure, with option -O3, using arm-none-eabi-gcc for STM32H7. I would be surprised it is different for Cortex M4 but it might be.

Comment: According to its C source, the `memset` function switches between `strb`, `str` and even `strd`, dynamically, depending on alignment of the pointers and the length parameter. Check the disassembly of your `libc.a`! I [tried it out](https://pastebin.com/krxtsVLk) and got the fast `memset` version as expected. When adding `-specs=nano.specs`, I got the slow-but-small `strb`-variant (not very surprising). Therefore, you need to remove that flag.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Removing that flag worked.  Unfortunately, it also increased code size by ~60kB, which isn't really a problem but is a lot considering I only wanted a faster memset.  Can't have it all I suppose.  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.  Otherwise I'll just add a note to my current one and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link *without* `-specs=nano.specs`. This will use the version of the C library, which includes `memset`, that is optimized for speed instead of size. This will pull in larger versions of many other functions (usual suspects: `printf` and `malloc`), which could again be optimized by additional linker options. Examining the disassembly and linker map file will help.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if GNU Tools ARM Embedded has an optimized memset, or how to access it via linker options, but it can be optimized in assembly manually.  After defining this, the linker used this version without complaining about a redefined function, which seems odd to me.  Overall speed increase is about 9x (i.e. this version takes about 11% as long as the original byte-wise method).

```
// optimized version of memset
// we split up the region into several segments
//
// base_ptr
// * store single bytes
// mid1
// * store words, 4 at a time
// mid2
// * store words, 1 at a time
// mid3
// * store single bytes
// end
//
// For large buffers, most of the time is spent between mid1 and mid2 which is
// highly optimized.
void * memset(void * base_ptr, int x, size_t length) {
  const uint32_t int_size = sizeof(uint32_t);
  static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == 4, "only supports 32 bit size");
  // find first word-aligned address
  uint32_t ptr = (uint32_t) base_ptr;
  // get end of memory to set
  uint32_t end = ptr + length;
  // get location of first word-aligned address at/after the start, but not
  // after the end
  uint32_t mid1 = (ptr + int_size - 1) / int_size * int_size;
  if (mid1 > end) {
    mid1 = end;
  }
  // get location of last word-aligned address at/before the end
  uint32_t mid3 = end / int_size * int_size;
  // get end location of optimized section
  uint32_t mid2 = mid1 + (mid3 - mid1) / (4 * int_size) * (4 * int_size);
  // create a word-sized integer
  uint32_t value = 0;
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < int_size; ++i) {
    value <<= 8;
    value |= (uint8_t) x;
  }
  __ASM volatile (
  // store bytes
  "b Compare1%=\n"
  "Store1%=:\n"
  "strb %[value], [%[ptr]], #1\n"
  "Compare1%=:\n"
  "cmp %[ptr], %[mid1]\n"
  "bcc Store1%=\n"
  // store words optimized
  "b Compare2%=\n"
  "Store2%=:\n"
  "str %[value], [%[ptr]], #4\n"
  "str %[value], [%[ptr]], #4\n"
  "str %[value], [%[ptr]], #4\n"
  "str %[value], [%[ptr]], #4\n"
  "Compare2%=:\n"
  "cmp %[ptr], %[mid2]\n"
  "bcc Store2%=\n"
  // store words
  "b Compare3%=\n"
  "Store3%=:\n"
  "str %[value], [%[ptr]], #4\n"
  "Compare3%=:\n"
  "cmp %[ptr], %[mid3]\n"
  "bcc Store3%=\n"
  // store bytes
  "b Compare4%=\n"
  "Store4%=:\n"
  "strb %[value], [%[ptr]], #1\n"
  "Compare4%=:\n"
  "cmp %[ptr], %[end]\n"
  "bcc Store4%=\n"
  : // no outputs
  : [value] "r"(value),
  [ptr] "r"(ptr),
  [mid1] "r"(mid1),
  [mid2] "r"(mid2),
  [mid3] "r"(mid3),
  [end] "r"(end)
  );
  return base_ptr;
}
```

Speed differences when operating on 32kB of data:

- original memset: 197045 ticks (~6 per byte)
- optimized memset: 22582 ticks (~0.7 per byte)
- max theoretical speed: 16384 ticks

The max speed is 2 ticks (speed of `str` instruction) per 4 bytes.

The original memset takes 16 bytes of code.  The new one takes 98 bytes.