# Prevent ArmClang to add calls to Standard C library

Tags: clang, stm32, keil

I am evaluating Keil Microvision IDE on STM32H753.

I am doing compiler comparison between ARMCC5 and AC6 in the different optimisation levels. AC6 is based on Clang.

My code is not using memcpy and I have unchecked "Use MicroLIB" in the project settings , However a basic byte per byte copy loop in my code is replaced by a memcpy with AC6 (only in "high" optimisation levels). It doesn't happen with ARMCC5.

I tried using compilation options to avoid that, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318229/llvm-optimizes-with-library-functions/21322637#21322637): `-ffreestanding` and `-disable-simplify-libcalls`, at both compiler and linker levels but it didn't change (for the second option, I get an error message saying that the option is not supported).

In the ARMCLANG reference guide i've found the options `-nostdlib -nostdlibinc` that prevent (??) the compiler to use any function of a standard lib.

However I still need the `math.h` function.

Do you know how to prevent clang to use functions from the Standard C Lib that are not **explicitely** called in the code ?

EDIT: here is a quick and dirty reproduceable example:
https://godbolt.org/z/AX8_WV
Please do not discuss the quality of this example, I know it is dumb !!, I know about memset, etc... It is just to understand the issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `memcpy`? There are some situations where a byte-loop as with `memcpy` is required, and avoiding `memcpy` would mean to inline/unroll said loop, possibly increasing program size.

Comment: There is no technical issue with memcpy. But the software i'm working on is certified in a scheme (safety software) that forbids to use any external software, including standard C library. Exceptions are possible but must be justified and are not adviced.

Comment: Also, in some constrained embedded environments, the `memcpy` provided with the Standard lib C is not efficient (for example on `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, it uses LDRB instructions where you can do LDM and save a lot of time)

Comment: So an inlined byte-copy-loop produced by the compiler would not count as external software, but the same loop from the C library does? Can you provide an example where a `memcpy` call is produced? You might be able to rewrite it in a way that doesn't require `memcpy`. Regarding slow implementations of library functions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57222626/4730685), which should apply to `memcpy` just as well.

Comment: The performance is actually not the main issue. The idea of not using external software is that every piece of code must be specified, documented, unit tested, etc. Sure, at the end I could take the assembly code of the memcpy and do all of this...

Comment: Isn't the the Standard C library already heavily specified (in fact, ISO-standardized), documented, and tested? If you choose an open source variant, you can work with its C source...

Comment: Of course I know the Standard lib C is very good (and probably better than my own code), well validated, etc... I don't want to discuss this issue further, it's off-topic

Comment: Well, can you provide an example where a `memcpy` call is produced? Maybe the call can be avoided.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a42m4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc know a lot about the memcpy, memset and similar functions and even they are called "the builtin functions". If you do not want those functions to be used by default just use the command line option `-fno-builtin`

https://godbolt.org/z/a42m4j

Comment: Oh my... you're right. Then I suggest you add this answer to the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318229/llvm-optimizes-with-library-functions/21322637#21322637